# Is there a better way to get shipping method meta/settings from order in WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have seen this question come up here and there, but it has not been fully answered. I know how to get the WC_Order_Item_Shipping information from an order, but how can I get a WC_Shipping_Method object from the orders shipping method item?

I have stored some custom options through a custom field in the admin setting page for the WooCommerce shipping methods. I want to get this field from an order. Right now I am doing this, and I can get to my information:

```
   foreach ($order->get_shipping_methods() as $shipping_method) {
            $options = get_option('woocommerce_' . $shipping_method->get_method_id() . '_' . $shipping_method->get_instance_id() . '_settings');
    }
```

But this does not feel future proof. If the structure of the saved data changes, then everything will break. I'd rather use the getter from WC_Shipping_Method `get_instance_option()`. The problem is that I am not allowed to instantiate such an object, and there does not seem to be a `wc_get_shipping_method()` function I can use to get the method based on it's instance ID, such as with orders and products.

I could go the long route and save this info to order meta after payment is made, but that also does not seem like an optimized way of doing it. I want to get the information as it is saved in the present moment, not as it was saved to an order when the order was made.

Is the way that I am doing it now the only way, or is there a better way?

EDIT:

This is the code that adds the custom field:

```
function shipping_instance_form_add_extra_fields($settings)
{
    $settings['custom_shipping_id'] = [
        'title' => 'Custom Shipping ID',
        'type' => 'number',
        'description' => '',
    ];

    return $settings;
}

function shipping_instance_form_fields_filters()
{
    $shipping_methods = WC()->shipping->get_shipping_methods();
    foreach ($shipping_methods as $shipping_method) {
        add_filter('woocommerce_shipping_instance_form_fields_' . $shipping_method->id, 'shipping_instance_form_add_extra_fields');
    }
}

add_action('woocommerce_init', 'shipping_instance_form_fields_filters');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you already have shipping method instance id you can simply create instance of class `WC_Shipping_Method` giving it instance id as constructor parameter like `$method = new WC_Shipping_Method($instance_id)`. After that you can use method `get_instance_option` to get value of that option like `$custom_shipping_id = $method->get_instance_option('custom_shipping_id');`

Answer (score 0):

That will do the trick:

```php
    $shipping_method = reset($order->get_shipping_methods());
    
    $shipping_class_names = WC()->shipping->get_shipping_method_class_names();
    
    $method_instance = new $shipping_class_names[$shipping_method->get_method_id()]( $shipping_method->get_instance_id() );
    
    $field_value = $method_instance->get_instance_option( 'your_custom_value' );
```

You can use it to add flexibility to your code and get value any desired instance option.